# Is there a way to solve the following differential equation for a sphere rising in a fluid?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, velocity, drag, differential-equations

Given the boundary conditions, how do I find the analytical solution (for the velocity) of the following expression:

$$ \left(\frac{2}{3} \pi \rho_f a^3 + \frac{4}{3} \pi \rho_s a^3\right) \frac{d ^2 x}{d t^2}  = \frac{4}{3} \pi a^3 (\rho_f - \rho_s)g - \frac{1}{2} \rho_f C_d \pi a^2 \left(\frac{d x}{d t}\right)^2$$

where $a$ is the radius of the sphere, and $\rho_s$ and $\rho_f$ are the density of the sphere and fluid respectively. Is this possible? If not, are there assumptions I can try to make so that I can get an approximation to the analytical solution?

Comment: There's no need for partials ($\partial$) because $x$ is a mere function of $t$.

Comment: The solution to the DE can be found here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/615472/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The differential equation**

A general trick in these cases is to solve the differential equation first for the speed, which is easy and first-order, and then integrate the speed to get the position.

Indeed, this is a differential equation of the form

$$d^2x/dt^2=A-B(dx/dt)^2$$

If we write $v=dx/dt$ this becomes
$$dv/dt = A-Bv^2$$ which [can be solved despite in general having a not so nice solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28t%29%20%20%3D%20A-B*%28y%28t%29%29%5E2).

Of course in your case we have:

$$A={{4\over 3}\pi a^3(\rho_f-\rho_s)g \over {2\over 3}\pi a^3(\rho_f+2\rho_s)} = 2g { (\rho_f-\rho_s) \over (\rho_f+2\rho_s)}$$

$$B={{1\over 2} \rho_f C_d \pi a^2 \over  {2\over 3}\pi a^3(\rho_f+2\rho_s)} = {3\over 4} {C_d \over a} {\rho_f \over (\rho_f+2\rho_s)}$$

notice that, dimensionally, $A$ is an acceleration and $B$ the inverse of a position (because $Bv^2$ is an acceleration). Also, $\sqrt{A/B}$ is a speed and $\sqrt{AB}$ the inverse of a time. We can use this fact later on to check the validity of our solutions.

Let us now see how we can reach that solution and how much better it looks in the case in which $v(0)=0$ i.e. your sphere starts without any initial velocity (for the more general case, refer to the link above and find the constant $c_1$ using any initial condition you might need).

**The analytical solution for the speed**

Very briefly, you can solve it by rewriting

$${dv \over A-Bv^2}=dt$$
and then by integrating this on both sides from our initial time $t_0$ to $t$:

$$\int_{t_0}^t {dv \over A-Bv^2} = t-t_0$$

By solving the [integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2F%281-x%5E2%29) on the left hand side:

$${1\over\sqrt{AB}} \tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{B\over A} v\right)+c  = t-t_0$$
where of course we added the necessary constants due to integration.

Now if we put $t_0=0$ and $c=0$ (equivalent to $v(0)=0$) we can solve it for $v$ and get

$$tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{B\over A} v\right)=\sqrt{AB}t$$ which then, applying $\tanh$ on both sides

$$\left(\sqrt{B\over A} v\right) = \tanh(\sqrt{AB}t)$$ and finally
$$v(t)=\sqrt{A\over B}\tanh(\sqrt{AB}t)$$ which is our solution for the speed.

A sketch of the solution for the velocity in the case where $v(0)=0$ is here [Note: the units are in terms of $A$ and $B$. Put in the right numbers in your constants to get the actual result you need]: it is a hyperbolic tangent, rising decently fast at the beginning but saturating at a limit speed given by $dv/dt=0$ i.e. when $v=A/B$ (when the $v$-dependent term equals the constant $A$):
[image]

**The analytical solution for the position**

Then of course you need to integrate again the speed $v(t)$ to get the position $x(t)=\int v(t)dt$. Again of course we use the initial condition $x(0)=0$ which is easy and also general, as starting at any other height would lead to the same solution albeit with a $+x(0)$ term, as there is no position-dependent force here.

If you then do also the [speed integration](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20tanh%28x%29) you get a solution of the form

$$x(t) = {1\over B}\ln(\cosh(\sqrt{AB}t))$$
meaning that you move with almost constant acceleration at the beginning (so $x(t)\sim v t +1/2at^2$ if $t\ll 1$  - that is why it starts looking like a parable) and then, once you reach terminal velocity, you go on at constant speed $v=A/B$ (linear behavior)

[image]

**Putting in the values**

So, using our definition of $A$ and $B$

$$A = 2g { (\rho_f-\rho_s) \over (\rho_f+2\rho_s)}$$

$$B = {3\over 4} {C_d \over a} {\rho_f \over (\rho_f+2\rho_s)}$$

we get (in the $v(0)=0$ and $x(0)=0$ assumption):

$$v(t)=\sqrt{ {8 g a\over 3 C_d} { (\rho_f-\rho_s) \over \rho_f } } \tanh \left(\sqrt{{6g C_d \over a} { \rho_f (\rho_f-\rho_s) \over (\rho_f+2\rho_s)^2} } t \right)$$

and for the position
$$x(t)=
{4\over 3} {a \over C_d} { (\rho_f+2\rho_s)\over \rho_f }\log(\cosh \left(\sqrt{{6g C_d \over a} { \rho_f (\rho_f-\rho_s) \over (\rho_f+2\rho_s)^2} } t \right))$$

**Summing up**

So the sphere starts without speed, accelerates under the effect of Archimedes' law but is sooner or later slowed down by the $-v^2$ term (friction/drag) which brings it to limit velocity, at which it moves until it reaches the surface. Reaching limit speed is a feature of most $v$-dependent friction forces.

Comment: Why, what's not so nice about the solution? With $c_1=0$ it becomes very simple.

Comment: yes, I edited to add the second part - still, not the easiest integral if you are not a fan of calculus  :D

Comment: Nice graph: 'a picture...'

Comment: Yes. I could spend some time and make the same graph, but I think a qualitative graph will answer most of OP's doubts. I unfortunately do not have time to do the precise graph now and reserve the right to edit my answer later on.

Comment: Done. I hope you will find the answers improved now.

Comment: OK. I made some minor edits. Tip for the future: $\mathrm{d}$ is better than plain $d$ because it emphases the operator nature.

Comment: Thanks for edits. It definitely looks better!

Comment: Thank you! Very clear. Indeed I made a couple of writing errors, but the first term on the l.h.s. is supposed to be the added mass term. Why should I not include this?

Comment: On the LHS you should only have the mass of the sphere (F=ma is applied to the sphere) - the mass of the fluid only plays a role in the buoyancy term on the RHS. Then I divided it by the mass of the sphere to get dv/dt alone on the LHS and that's why you get that $\rho_s$ below in the A-term. But whatever, the details of $A$ and $B$ are irrelevant to the solution: just double check your terms, find your right "A" and "B" and there you go!

Comment: Just to be sure we are on the same page, I am referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Added_mass#Applications

Comment: I see - did not know about it. So just xhange the definition of A and B - i will edit later!

Comment: Now complete, with added mass. I just hope i did not make any mistake in writing $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your notation, we are dealing with and *ordinary differential equation* here:
$$
A\ddot{x}=B - C\dot{x}^2
$$
If we define function $y=\dot{x}$, it becomes
$$
A\dot{y} = B -Cy^2,
$$
which is trivially solvable
$$
\frac{Ady}{B - Cy^2}=dt
$$
and then integrating both sides.

Note that this is a particular case of the [Ricatti differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation), which is solvable for $x$-dependent coefficients.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!